# Language suddenly changed to something besides English

Tags: facebook

I log into Facebook and it is in Spanish or some language I don't recognize.  How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Go on http://facebook.com and login there, not on http://es-es.facebook.com. That should do the trick.